# Filter a multidimensional array on multiple levels and return a column of data from qualifying subsets

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have below set of data

```
[{
    "sr_team": [{
        "classifications": "BPO",
        "email": "maynard_gregory@example.com",
        "names": "Maynard Gregory"
    }],
    "jr_team": [{
        "names": "Mr. Curtis Zemlak I",
        "email": "curtis_zemlak@example.com",
        "available": false
    }, {
        "names": "Prof. Naomi Eichmann II",
        "email": "naomi_eichmann@example.com",
        "available": true
    }]
}, {
    "sr_team": [{
        "classifications": "Tech",
        "email": "olivia_dawson@example.com",
        "names": "Olivia Dawson"
    }],
    "jr_team": [{
        "names": "Benjamin George",
        "email": "benjamin_george@example.com",
        "available": true
    }]
}]
```

From the above data, I need the **names** of `jr_team` who have `available` as `true`. i.e. the code should return below two values.

```
[
    'Prof. Naomi Eichmann II',
    'Benjamin George'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you could also opt for a slightly more concise snippet to determine qualifying values.

Check out the [demo](https://3v4l.org/IU92X):

```
$store = [];
foreach ($arr as $teams) {
    foreach ($teams['jr_team'] as $record) {
        if ($record['available']) {
            $store[] = $record['names'];
        }
    }
}
```

Result (`$store`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Prof. Naomi Eichmann II
    [1] => Benjamin George
)
```